# OneToOne relation with Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm trying to create a simple OneToOne relation between my User and Profile entity, here is my controller: http://pastie.org/5068108, my User entity: http://pastie.org/5068124 and my Profile entity : http://pastie.org/5068131  But I always get this weird error :

Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Test/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 98.

This error appear when Im trying to persist() my form.

Can someone help me please, i struggle with this error which mean nothing for me. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your $profile attribute in your User entity should be:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Test\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user")
* @JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $profile;
```

And you will have to add the following in your Profile entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Test\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="profile")
*/
private $user;
```

After that, apply changes:

> app/console doctrine:generate:entities Test
>
> app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

**EDITED:** I forgot to add the JoinColumn annotation, as @shima5 pointed out.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help, I made this correct already and nothing change, the error style here :/

Comment: Apart from that "Array to string conversion" Notice, are you getting any errors when doing persist()? Have you checked your database to see if your objects are being persisted?

Comment: my Profile object is not persisted in my database, this error appear when the persist() function is launched...I've do a var_dump of my Profile object and there all informations from the form, but can't persist after.

Comment: Here is my last code: Controller = pastie.org/5068338 User entity = pastie.org/5068345 and Profile entity = pastie.org/5068348 the error still the same :/

Answer (score 1):

In User.php :

```
   /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Test\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profile")
     * @JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $profile;
```

It's an unidirectional association.

You can't use mappedBy="user" alone because it's bidirectional, you need to add inversedBy="profile" in your Profile like this :

```
   /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
```

And User :

```
   /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Test\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $profile;
```

Comment: Thanks shima5, but nothing change, this error still when my controller try to persist my form...

Comment: Here is my last code: Controller = http://pastie.org/5068338 User entity = http://pastie.org/5068345 and Profile entity = http://pastie.org/5068348 the error still the same :/

Comment: like i said, in the controller you need to set an user to your profile before persisting it.

Comment: It's what I've done but the error appear when I'm trying to persist.